# Isometric embedding of a hemisphere of $\mathbb{S}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Herman Karcher says at the end of the first page in [Riemannian Center of Mass and so called karcher mean](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.2087v1.pdf) that *for the Hiperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$ and a hemisphere of $\mathbb{S}^n$ there are standard isometrics embeddings into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.*

I would like to know if this means that there exist a transformation $\Phi$ such that for $d(x,y) = \| \Phi(x) - \Phi(y) \|_2$. If this is true, then which is such transformation in the case of a hemisphere of $\mathbb{S}^n$ with the great circle distance i.e. $d(x,y) = \arccos(\langle x, y \rangle)$

Comment: the link you provided does not work.

Comment: As stated this is wrong: there is not a (smooth) isometric embedding of $\Bbb H^n$ into $\Bbb R^{n+1}$. Perhaps the author means $\Bbb R^{n,1}$, Minkowski space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually he just says that "The hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$ and a hemisphere of $\mathbb{S}^n$ are not linear spaces, but
they have standard isometric embeddings into
$\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$". Your citation is slightly confusing as it seems to imply that the distance between the two manifolds is preserved, which does not make sense.

What it means is that they can be embedded into (Euclidean or Minkowski) $n+1$ space such that the induced distance is the same as the distance in the abstract Riemannian manifolds, i.e. the distance between any two points $x, y$ is the $\inf$ of all lengths of curves (in the manifold) joining $x$ and $y$.

The embedding of the sphere is just the boundary of the unit ball. The embedding of hyperbolic space is (one component) of the unit sphere with respect to the Minkowski Metric (i.e the set defined by $x_0^2 = \sum_{i>0} x_i^2$ (and is isometric wrt to the Minkowski metric).

Comment: Thanks. This answers my question which was: Am I understanding this correctly? The answer: NO.

Comment: I re wrote the question in order to make sense as a citation.

Comment: How can you embedd a sphere isometrically into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$? The map you describe does not preserve distance.

Comment: @koch The standard embedding (i.e. the inclusion of the boundary of the unit ball into the ambient space) is an isometric embedding. This is a tautological statement, since the metric on the sphere is induced by this embedding. When one says that this preserves distance then distance always refers to the intrinsic distance (as described in my answer). Isometric does _not_ mean, that the distance in the sphere is the same as the distance in the ambient space, it means that the metric tensors (one from the embedding, one from scalar product of the ambient space) are the same.

Comment: I see, thank you! So it should be right that there is no distance preserving embeddings of $S^n$, right?

Comment: @koch If, for the target, you are referring to the distance of the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that's correct.

Comment: Does there exist such $n$ such that there is a distance preserving embedding of $S^2$ into $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @koch not in the sense you are looking at it.